# update with multiple OR statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large number of changes to make to a database.

The records in question have a column 'status' which i need to update only if certain statuses aren't recorded.

```
select `status`,`source_id` from vicidial_list where list_id = "444662" and source_id = "3791775X"
```

returns

```
status,source_id    
ADC,3791775X
```

ADC is a status that should be ignored during my update

if I run

```
update `db`.`vicidial_list` set `status`='SUPR' where list_id = "444662" and source_id = "3791775X" and `status` != "ADC"
```

this works, the status value is not updated. However I have multiple statuses I need to ignore, and so I need to run

```
update `db`.`vicidial_list` set `status`='SUPR' where list_id = "444662" and source_id = "3791775X" and `status` != "ASUPP" OR `status` !=  "ADC"
```

There are multiple OR statements after this one. However if I execute that and then run my earlier select statement

```
status,source_id    
SUPR,3791775X
```

The field has updated even though my OR statement should prevent this?

I'm clearly missing something, how do I go about adding multiple OR statements to this statement?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `OR` you want to use `AND`. E.g., if a status is `'ASUPP'`, it isn't `'ADC'`. That's a match and the row gets updated.

Another possibility is to use:

```
status NOT IN ('ASUPP',
               'ADC')
```

Side note: Better use single quotes for enclosing strings, to be compatible with the standard and other DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `AND` instead of `OR`

```
update `db`.`vicidial_list` set `status`='SUPR' 
  where list_id = "444662" and source_id = "3791775X" 
   and `status` != "ASUPP" and `status` !=  "ADC"
```